# Best practice for setOnClickListener in custom nav drawer

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am using a custom nav drawer in my app. For switching activities, I am using setOnClickListener for each button. But i think that might consume a lot of memory as the same code is to be loaded in each activity every time. So is there any efficient way to handle on click listener for menu like switch case?

My code for nav-item clicks.

```
 Button oneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_one);
    Button twoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_two);
    Button threeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_three);
    Button fourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_four);
    Button fiveeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_five);

        oneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(firstIntent);
        }
        });

        twoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Intent secondIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(secondIntent);

        }
        });

        threeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Intent threeButton = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(thirdIntent);

        }
        });

        threeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Intent fourButton = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FouthActivity.class);
        startActivity(fourthIntent);

        }
        });

        fourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Intent fiveButton = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FifthouthActivity.class);
        startActivity(fifthIntent);
        }
        });
```

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: What do you mean "each activity"? The NavDrawer should switch Fragments of *one Activity*

Comment: I have to put the click listeners in every activity to make menu work. @cricket_007

Comment: Check the question @Anil

Comment: Why are you switching activities instead of fragments? Surely this consumes memory. The default Navigation Drawer switches fragments which is a better approach.

Comment: hey follow this [link](https://medium.com/@janishar.ali/navigation-drawer-android-example-8dfe38c66f59)

Comment: I am using Activities in my app. Earlier I asked a question about it, but got no answer about that. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262327/how-can-i-avoid-memory-leaks-in-my-android-app) @Abhi

Comment: Your previous question *was* too broad. Yes, Fragments are more preferred, but it depends on your application design, which was not mentioned in the previous question. NavDrawers are most generally useful for Fragments. Only start a new Activity when you need to completely change contents of your screen

Comment: I am displaying data from different API in my app. The only thing common in my activities is they all use recyclerview, but with different layout. So will using fragment help me in reducing memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method , it may help you

Don't forget to add this

```
class YourClass ... implements View.OnClickListener

    onCreate {
        Button oneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_one);
        Button twoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_two);
        Button threeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_three);
        Button fourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_four);
        Button fiveeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_five);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        oneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        twoButton .setOnClickListener(this);
        threeButton .setOnClickListener(this);
        fourButton .setOnClickListener(this);
        fiveeButton .setOnClickListener(this);
    }//onCreate method ends here

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {

            case R.id.nav_one:
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                Intent firstIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(firstIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_two:
               //same way other buttons also

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but i want to know if there is any efficient way to handle click listeners. My app uses about 40-50 MB of memory and i want to reduce that. So will using switch case help?

Comment: @Ganesh switch case isn't saving memory. Having one `View.OnClickListener` is... However, that will not save MB worth of size

Comment: I agree with @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you.